# PHP Mongo connection Blacklisting

Tags: php, mongodb, driver, blacklist

In the [legacy PHP MongoDB Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) a connection can be blacklisted as mentioned in stack overflow question: [MongoDB Blacklisted Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918864/mongodb-blacklisted-fatal-error).

Does anyone know if this behavior also applies in PHP's supported [MongoDB Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) ?

Comment: You should ask that questions here : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/519

Short answer seems to be yes.

The current driver uses [libmongoc](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver) internally, which implements the [Server Discovery and Monitoring specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst). The PHP and HHVM drivers both use a single-threaded monitoring implementation, in which sockets are shared for monitoring and application usage (multi-threaded implementations have a separate pool of connection used exclusively for monitoring). This single-thread approach uses a [five-second timeout](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#cooldownms) for ignoring a server after encountering a network error, which is analogous to the blacklisting behavior of the legacy driver.